# Scanning only x number of instance in a collection using MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, database

I have a collection in this format:

```
{"Name":"Alex", "Work":"Mgr", "Hobbies":["Music", "Sports"]},
{"Name":"Jake", "Work":"Professor", "Hobbies":["Cycling", "Singing", "Music"]}
... and many more
```

Now to return all documents that has `Music` as one of the `hobbies`

```
db.office.find({"Hobbies":"Music"})
```

Now how do I limit the scan to just `X` instance of `Music` in the above collection without using `limit`

Note: All the `Hobbies` are indexed.

Comment: What would be the problem with limit here? It might help your question to state the problem you see with using that in this case.

Comment: @NeilLunn I do not want to scan all the instances of Music in the collection. For performance reason that is. I just want to scan any X instances of Music and then come out of the query

Answer (score 1):

Well you can provide [**`$maxScan`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/maxScan/) as a cursor modifier.

Adding to your data a little:

```
{ "Name" : "Alex", "Work" : "Mgr", "Hobbies" : [ "Music", "Sports" ] }
{ "Name" : "Jake", "Work" : "Professor", "Hobbies" : [ "Cycling", "Singing", "Music" ] }
{ "Name" : "Bill", "Work" : "Student", "Hobbies" : [ "XBox" ] }
{ "Name" : "Ben", "Work" : "Student", "Hobbies" : [ "Music" ] }
```

Issuing a query like:

```
db.office.find({ Hobbies: "Music"})._addSpecial("$maxScan", 2)
```

Just returns the first result. And the explain output:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor Hobbies_1",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 2,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 2,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
            "Hobbies" : [
                    [
                            "Music",
                            "Music"
                    ]
            ]
    },
    "server" : "ubuntu:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

Shows that despite there being more possible matches, we did not look at all of them.

See also [cursor tools](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.7/api/pymongo/cursor.html) in the pymongo documentation.